# This function gives me the error "warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] }"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

When I compile this code I get the error that was stated in the title, but I am not sure what is causing it. I have checked other similar questions and I still can't seem to figure out why it is happening.

```
int dictionary::getRank(string Word)
{
    int Rank = 0;
    string str;
    bool found = false;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < WORD_COUNT; i++)
        if (word[i] == Word)
            found = true;
    if (found == true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < WORD_COUNT; i++)
        {
            str = word[i];
            if (str == Word)
                return Rank;
            Rank++;
        }
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: You can get rid if the error / warning by removing just the `else`. Keep the `return -1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look really carefully at that code, and think what would happen if the 1st loop sets `found` to true, and then the 2nd loop reaches `WORD_COUNT` without finding a matching word.  Logically, that *can't* actually happen at runtime, but the compiler doesn't know that.  All it sees is a flow path that is missing a `return` statement, hence the warning.

The easiest way to fix this is to just get rid of the `else`:

```cpp
int dictionary::getRank(string Word)
{
    int Rank = 0;
    string str;
    bool found = false;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < WORD_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        if (word[i] == Word)
            found = true;
    }

    if (found)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < WORD_COUNT; ++i)
        {
            str = word[i];
            if (str == Word)
                return Rank;
            ++Rank;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

However, the 2nd loop is redundant and should be removed completely.  The function can be simplified to this:

```cpp
int dictionary::getRank(string Word)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < WORD_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        if (word[i] == Word)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Which can be simplified further if you use [`std::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead of a manual loop:

```cpp
int dictionary::getRank(string Word)
{
    string* end = &word[WORD_COUNT];
    string* iter = std::find(word, end, Word);
    if (iter != end) {
        return static_cast<int>(iter - word);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Ahh ok, so I would need to add a return statement inside of the if statement, but outside of the for loop, correct?

Comment: `Rank` isn't even needed.  It's the same as `i`.

Comment: @PrestonWatts yes, you would need a `return` after the 2nd loop. I have updated my answer to show this.